# Using linking table for restricting entities in many-to-many relationship otherwise no restrictions

Tags: database, hibernate, jpa, database-design, many-to-many

I have a many-to-many relationship between PromoCode and User. A user can have many promocodes and a promoCode can be valid for many users. The default case is that a promoCode will be valid for all users.

User(userId,...)

PromoCode(promoCodeId,...)

In this many-to-many relationship, I have created a secondary table UserPromoCode(userId, promoCodeId) in which we store only promocodes which are restricted for few customers. How can I deal the default case?

Do I have to add records in UserPromoCode table for all users? It will be obviously expensive when a new promoCode is created
Or do I have to save only restricted ones and  apply if else condition in my application logic like if there is no record for a promoCode in UserPromoCode table, the promocode applies to all?

In short, how we deal with problem of optional restricting an entity for some other entity otherwise by default no restriction in many-to-many relationships?

I don't want to apply if else conditions at application logic. I simply want to apply a query that can give me all PromoCodes for a user (restricted or unrestricted ones)

Comment: Your questions show that you understand the trade-offs.  Either you add rows in UserPromoCode for all users or you use if-then logic to test for universal promo codes.

Comment: Do all "special" customers qualify for all promo codes?

Comment: Yes. Usually promo codes are applied on all customers, however, there are some promo codes which are specific to some customers.

Answer (score 1):

```
-- Promo code CDE exists.
--
promo {CDE}
   PK {CDE}
```

```
-- Promo code CDE is special (restricted).
--
promo_special {CDE}
           PK {CDE}

FK {CDE} REFERENCES promo {CDE}
```

```sql
-- Promo code CDE is available to all users.
--
CREATE VIEW promo_all
AS
SELECT CDE from promo
EXCEPT
SELECT CDE from promo_special ;
```

```
-- User USR exists.
--
user_ {USR}
   PK {USR}
```

### Option 1

A subset of (special) users qualify for all special promo codes.

```
-- User USR qualifies for all special promo codes.
--
user_special {USR}
          PK {USR}

FK {USR} REFERENCES user_ {USR}
```

```sql
-- User USR qualifies for promo code CDE.
--
CREATE VIEW user_promo
AS

SELECT USR, CDE
FROM       user_
CROSS JOIN promo_all

UNION

SELECT USR, CDE
FROM       user_special
CROSS JOIN promo_special ;
```

#### Option 2

Some users qualify for some of special promo codes.

```
-- User USR qualifies for special promo code CDE.
--
user_special {USR, CDE}
          PK {USR, CDE}

FK1 {USR} REFERENCES user_ {USR}

          FK2 {CDE} REFERENCES
promo_special {CDE}
```

```sql
-- User USR qualifies for promo code CDE.
--
CREATE VIEW user_promo
AS

SELECT USR, CDE
FROM       user_
CROSS JOIN promo_all

UNION

SELECT USR, CDE
FROM user_special ;
```

### For Both Options

To get all promo codes for a specific user.

```sql
-- Specific user (USR = specific_user) qualifies
-- for promo code CDE.
--
SELECT CDE FROM user_promo WHERE USR = specific_user ;
```

---

Note:

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
FK = Foreign Key
```